# How can I see what is inside a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, cout

When I check the values inside of the `homework` vector using `cout` it seems to only be returning the value inside `homework[0]`. Can somebody look over my code and let me know where I'm going wrong?

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter midterm and final: " << endl;
    double midterm, gfinal;
    cin >> midterm >> gfinal;
    cout << "Enter all your homework grades, " << endl;

    double x;

    cin >> x;

    // initing a vector object named homework
    vector<double> homework;
    // show debug on the vector
    while (homework.size() != 3)
        homework.push_back(x);
    if (homework.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << endl << "You need to enter at least one number";
        return 1;
    }

    // vector before sorting
    // since cout << homework did not seem to work I could always just write a debug function to iterate over structures and print them to the console
    cout << homework[0] << endl; 
    cout << homework[1] << endl;
    cout << homework[2] << endl;

    // sort the vector here
    sort(homework.begin(), homework.end());

    // vector after sorting
    //cout << homework;
    cout << homework[0] << endl;
    cout << homework[1] << endl;
    cout << homework[2] << endl;


    int mid = homework.size() / 2;
    cout << "The below is mid" << endl;
    cout << mid << endl;

    double median;
    if (homework.size() % 2 == 0)
        median = (homework[mid - 1] + homework[mid]) / 2;
    else
        median = homework[mid];
    //streamsize prec = cout.precision(3);
    cout << "Your course grade is "
        << 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * gfinal + 0.4 * median << endl;
    //cout.precision(prec);

    return 0;

}
```

This is the specific code that is causing me confusion:

```
// vector before sorting
// since cout << homework did not seem to work I could always just write a debug function to iterate over structures and print them to the console

cout << homework[0] << endl; 
cout << homework[1] << endl;
cout << homework[2] << endl;

// sort the vector here
sort(homework.begin(), homework.end());

// vector after sorting
//cout << homework;
cout << homework[0] << endl;
cout << homework[1] << endl;
cout << homework[2] << endl;
```

When the program starts it asks for 2 values, so I plugged in 100 100.
Then it asks for 3 values so I used 80 90 100 the `cout` of all the homework positions is showing 80 when I am expecting 80 90 100. 
The actual program works as the final `cout` returns 92 as expected.

Comment: Can you pointer your finger to which part of your program: 1) reads one value, 2) adds this value to a vector, 3) goes back to step 1 until three values are read. Hint: your `while` loop does not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the bugs have been fixed already. I will add a "more-C++"-style solution using STL algorithms.

For filling the vector, I will use `std::copy_n`. Meaning, read n values from `std::cin` and insert them into the target vector.

And for your question

> How can I see what is inside a vector?

the solution is, iterate over the elements in the vector and copy the vectors values to `ctd::cout`. For this we will use the `std::ostream_iterator`

Please note: I always use qualifed names lke `std::cout`. Please consider. And I rarly use `std::endl`, becuase this always call flush, which is in most cases not needed. Also: All variables should always be initialized. Always.

And then, I added many comments. Please also consider. This improves the code readability and quality drastically.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

constexpr size_t NumberOfHomeworkGrades = 3U;

int main()
{
    // Print title and ask use to enter data
    std::cout << "\nCalculation of course grade\n\nPlease enter midterm and final: " << '\n';
    double midterm{ 0.0 };
    double gfinal{ 0.0 };
    std::cin >> midterm >> gfinal;

    // Ask the use to enter the howmwork grades
    std::cout << "Please Enter "<< NumberOfHomeworkGrades << " homework grades\n";

    // Get the data from the user and put it into the vector
    std::vector<double> homeworkGrades{};

    std::copy_n(
        std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin),   // We will iterate over std::cin and read data
        NumberOfHomeworkGrades,                    // Over all we read data NumberOfHomeworkGrades times
        std::back_inserter(homeworkGrades)         // And we psuh the data into our homeworkGrades-vector
    );

    // Show the vector before sorting. Simply copy all data in the vector to std::cout using the ostream_iterator
    std::cout << "\n\nEntered grades before sort\n";
    std::copy(homeworkGrades.begin(), homeworkGrades.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // Sort the vector here
    std::sort(homeworkGrades.begin(), homeworkGrades.end());

    // Show the vector adter sorting. Simply copy all data in the vector to std::cout using the ostream_iterator
    std::cout << "\n\nSorted grades\n";
    std::copy(homeworkGrades.begin(), homeworkGrades.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // Calculate the median
    double median{ 0 };

    // First calculate the mid, to do the calculation only one time and to show the result
    size_t mid{ homeworkGrades.size() / 2 };

    if (!homeworkGrades.empty())
        if (homeworkGrades.size() % 2 == 0) 
            median = (homeworkGrades[mid - 1] + homeworkGrades[mid]) / 2;
        else
            median = homeworkGrades[mid];

    // Show the result to the user
    std::cout << "\n\nThe mid value is (maybe truncated): " << mid
        << "\nThe median value is:                " << median
        << "\n\nYour course grade is: " << 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * gfinal + 0.4 * median << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In your code:

```
double x;

cin >> x; // <-- reading from cin only once

// initing a vector object named homework
vector<double> homework;
// show debug on the vector
while (homework.size() != 3)
    homework.push_back(x); // <- inserting same value three times
```

you are reading from `cin` only once, i.e., you are reading a single value. Then, you are inserting that read value three times into the vector `homework`. Therefore, `homework[0]`, `homework[1]` and `homework[2]` contain the same value.

---

Consider placing `cin >> x` inside the `while` loop to read three times from `cin` instead of just once, i.e., read from `cin` on each iteration of the loop:

```
vector<double> homework;

while (homework.size() < 3) {
   double x;
   cin >> x;
   homework.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to need to play with it some more, but I'm curious how I was getting different answers that "felt" correct? It may have just been garbage values sitting in the empty vector positions?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the bug that El Profesor pointed, for iterating a vector in modern C++, all you have to do is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> homework{ 70,80,90 }; // For the example

    // "See what is inside the vector":
    for (auto grade : homework)
        std::cout << grade << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That repeated `std::endl` is really wasteful. Don't do that.